# How did they do this with youtube

Tags: embed

Hi in the below code if i change domain name the video is not streaming saying that the site has no permision

For the safty of orginal owner i have changed domain in below code

https://www.youtube.com/embed/8EDIJcaAq8Y?iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0&playsinline=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&start=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cox.com&widgetid=7&showinfo=0

My question is does he take any permision from YT for that site or any other issues

If yes can any one help me with the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the `www.cox.com` part of the URL.

I've changed it and typed `https://www.youtube.com/embed/8EDIJcaAq8Y?iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0&playsinline=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&start=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itdoeswork.com&widgetid=7&showinfo=0` instead and opened in a new tab it did work.

What's your exact problem? (I can't comment, pardon me.)

Also tried here:

[image: imgur-codepen]